# how to update ng-model for value entered in textarea that was created dynamicly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how can i update angular model for the value entered by user in text area.
i have to create text area dynamically. how can i update model of angular js when user press ok after giving the value

```
function relation(event){

 var display_area=document.getElementById("cart");
    // '<textarea maxlength="50" cols="18" rows="4"  id="getRelation" style="border: solid 2px; "></textarea>'
 var relation_wrapper=document.createElement("div");
 relation_wrapper.style.border="solid,3px";
 relation_wrapper.style.borderColor="black";
 relation_wrapper.style.width="100px";
 relation_wrapper.style.height="500px";
 relation_wrapper.style.backgroundColor="red";
 var lineBreak=document.createElement("br");
 var get_relation_button=document.createElement("button");
 var button_text=document.createTextNode("OK");
 relation_wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement("TEXTAREA"));
 relation_wrapper.appendChild(lineBreak);
 get_relation_button.appendChild(button_text);
 relation_wrapper.appendChild(get_relation_button);
 display_area.appendChild(relation_wrapper); }
```

this will create a textarea and a button 
now i want to update the value in angular model when user press the button .
any idea how can i do that

Comment: What model? There is absolutely no angular code in question whatsoever and we have no idea how you implement code shown

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not clear enough but just recompile your dynamic content using $compile service and rest will be handled by angular, like:

```
$compile(angular.element(display_area).html())($scope);
```

Comment: actually i am quiet new to angular ...is there any way that i can get a bubble pop up through which i can get the text and call it on drag and drop using angular.??